# How to use pillar data as a variable in script deployed using saltstack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to use a value defined inside a pillar, as a variable to be setup at deployment time, e.g :

```
cat pillar/passwd.sls 
server_gpg: 'gpgPassword'
```

I'd like to use the value of "server_gpg" variable inside a script, I tried this but this does work :

```
/usr/bin/gpg --yes --passphrase '{{ pillar['gpgPassword'] }}' [...]
```

I am sure this is a noob (which is what I am) question, but I could not find a working tips within the Salt / Jinja docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my bad, after some more research in the saltstack i found out that I was just missing a :

```
- template: jinja
```

definition in my state declaration.